# What should I use to authenticate user in login with nodejs

Tags: mysql, node.js, express

I'm using MySQL in ExpressJS. I've inserted data in my database and now I need to authenticate the  user with the data present in the database, e.g.:

```
username: john 
password: 123
```

Now when ever john logs in with the username and password it should check whether it is present in MySQL or not as I've a little bit background in PHP in which we use the following approach:

```
$query=mysql_query("SELECT * from login WHERE username='".$_POST['username']."' AND password='".$_POST['password']."' ") or die(mysql_error());

if(mysql_fetch_row($query)>0){
    echo "Login Sucessfully";
        }>
    else{
            echo "Wrong Id or Password";
        }
```

Comment: In future, please spend more time writing or formatting your post. Formatting help can be found [here](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help). Furthermore, most keyboards have a CAPS LOCK these days; please  use it next time.

Comment: international caps lock day is 28th of june, not 18th :-)

Comment: ok but u guys didnt reply my question

Comment: You didn't ask a question. You just gave a list of requirements and posted some PHP code.

Comment: https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the [auth example](https://github.com/visionmedia/express/blob/master/examples/auth/app.js) from express' github page. It'll take some time to understand, especially if you're not used to asynchronous programming - but this example should do.

This example uses no database at all, but you can try to implement an my-sql database using @felixge's [mysql module](https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql).